# Are credit unions or other non-bank financial institutions available in Mexico?

Tags: credit-unions, mexico

Are there credit unions, or other non-bank financial institutions available in Mexico, to the general public?

Comment: Though some may answer this question with product recommendations, the OP only asked whether they exist, the accepted answer seems to also be on topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course there are.  In Mexico they're called *caja popular* and one of the largest is [Caja Popular Mexicana](http://www.cpm.coop/).  There are also microfinance institutions (like [Compartamos](http://www.compartamos.com/wps/portal)) but Mexico is [famous for charging the highest interest rates](http://microfinancehub.com/2010/03/25/microfinance-goes-awry-case-study-of-bank-compartamos%E2%80%99-interest-rates/) in the world (well over 100%).

For more information on lenders (and ratings plus a really cool APR calculation tool) visit [Microfinance Transparency](http://www.mftransparency.org/).